# Zen Cart shipping estimator

Tags: php, e-commerce, zen-cart

I'm working on zen-cart and I'm new to it, here is my situation.

There is one live site, one development site and localhost.

The development site functionality are same as the live site,

My problem is when I click estimate shipping the amount I get in live site and in localhost are equal but the amount I get in development site is not right (increased amount).

I have no idea from where the shipping estimation is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your database: Admin->Configuration->Shipping for your Postal Code - perhaps they are different on development vs. localhost.  This is one of the inputs to the shipping estimate.

Comment: Thanks man I checked it and made some changes and the issue got fixed, Thanks for your help :)